# Flutter app rejected by Google Play store: Unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier

Tags: flutter, google-play

As the title says, this is the message I received after submitting my flutter app to the Google Play store. I'm not sure what to do here as I haven't even written any Java/Swift code that I could search. I'm guessing it's a 3rd party dependency that's causing this. What's the best way to figure out the offending flutter package that's causing this?
And why isn't there a hint like a class name to give me a starting point to look?

[image]

Comment: I've got the warning too :(

Comment: I had the same problem, in my case was linked to flutter braintree
https://github.com/pikaju/flutter-braintree/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

Look for 3rd party package that is connecting to internet, quite possibly to an "unsecure" website without "https://"